# ROSberryPi For GoPiGo3: Install Pkgs or different Variant?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to create a ROS Kinetic installation on Raspbian-Stretch that has the packages needed for a GoPiGo3 node.

I followed [ROSberryPiInstalling ROS Kinetic on the Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi) and chose the "recommended by the wiki" ROS-COMM variant.  (The wiki states only the ROS-COMM and DESKTOP variants have been "tested in Kinetic".)

I followed [ROS-GOPIGO3_NODE: INSTALLATION](https://github.com/ros-gopigo/gopigo3_node/wiki/Installation), but my  ROS is missing the following packages:

- geometry_msgs
- rospy
- sensor_msgs
- nav_msgs
- tf     (listed in packages.xml but is deprecated by tf2)

Should I ??

- install only the missing packages,
- start over and install the "tested" DESKTOP variant, or
  or start over and attempt one of the REP-131 (groovy variants?)
- install "ros-base (ros,ros_comm)", or
- install "robot(extends ros-base with a bunch of stacks)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332388/rosberrypi-for-gopigo3:-install-pkgs-or-different-variant?/) by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2019-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried the "install only the missing packages" and have SUCCESS!

This is how I did it:

> ====== adding packages/stacks needed for GoPiGo3_Node
>
> $ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws $
> rosinstall_generator ros_comm
> geometry_msgs rospy sensor_msgs
> nav_msgs tf --rosdistro kinetic --deps
> --wet-only --tar >kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall
>
> $ wstool merge -t src
> > kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall
> >      Performing actions: 
> > 
> >      Add new elements:   actionlib,  angles,  common_msgs/actionlib_msgs, 
> > common_msgs/geometry_msgs, 
> > common_msgs/nav_msgs, 
> > common_msgs/sensor_msgs,  geometry/tf,
> > geometry2/tf2,  geometry2/tf2_msgs, 
> > geometry2/tf2_py,  geometry2/tf2_ros
> > 
> > Config changed, maybe you need run
> > wstool update to update SCM entries.
> > Overwriting
> > /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/.rosinstall
> > 
> > update complete.
> > 
> > $ wstool update -t src
>
> $ rosdep install -y --from-paths src
> > --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -r --os=debian:stretch
> > 
> > $ sudo
> ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated
> --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic -j2

---

Originally posted by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) with karma: 327 on 2019-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1